# how to make a thread that loops a temporized action in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sleep

I want,in my mainactivity,to start a thread that does some stuff every x seconds.
is this aproach correct?

taken from my oncreate method:

```
  Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    sleep(5000);

                    do stuff

    };
    thread.start();
```

if it's relevant it starts a videoplayer and checks its buffer every 5 seconds.

Comment: use a TimerTask. Be aware that to touch the ui you need to post on the ui thread queue

Comment: @blackbelt basically I should replace the world Thread with timertask in my code? using this reference http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html it would seem so. why would it be better tshan using a thread? I don't have to interact with the ui,just do some calculation.

Comment: why don't you like your existing approach? It looks quite ok if forget about exception handling

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I've never ever implemented a thread before, and I read that using sleep is not recomended due to the fact that it may freeze the main thread (wich seems pretty strange tbh,but some guy around the web says so...)

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` can freeze the main thread only if you're calling it from the main thread... Here you call it from separate thread, so there is nothing to worry about. But if you want to follow good style recommendations, take a look at Java's `ExecutorService` and especially at its `ScheduledExecutorService` subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create flexible and effective timer using Java's `ExecutorService`:

```
// create executor that consists of 1 thread
final ExecutorService e = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

// schedule it to execute every 5000 ms starting from now
((ScheduledExecutorService) e).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // your repeating task
     }                  
}, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This approach is more flexible and, if Java docs don't lie, more precise since it is independent on system clock changes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html